# htaccess to block direct access

Tags: .htaccess

can you help me to block indexing and block direct access to my data, so anyone can not download domain/data/File1.pdf, they only can download file and open from my display page in this case view.php, in file view.php i used google docs.i have used this in my htaccess but it didnt work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(view.php|view).* [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(pdf|zip|doc|rar)$ - [F,NS,L]
```

here is my folder structure

```
- include
- data/
--- File1.pdf
--- File2.zip
--- File3.doc
--- File3.rar
- index.php
- view.php
- themes.js
```

Answer (score 0):

what you should be looking for is [.htaccess hotlinking prevention](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=.htaccess%20hotlinking%20prevention)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)$ - [NC,F,L]
```