# Showing PDF's with blocking direct link (.htaccess)

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm trying to show my PDF files in my webpages but block the direct access to the files.
I'm trying to do this by using a .htaccess file like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from {MY_IP}
```

Where MY_IP is my server IP address (ex. 11.22.333.444), but when I do this my server can't access the files anymore. I'm showing the PDF's with this code:

```
    <object data="downloads/PDF/doc.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

<p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
You can <a href="doc.pdf">click here to
download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```

The webpage just stays blank (it can't load it).
Is there anything I'm missing with .htaccess?

Thanks for helping in advance!

Marc

Comment: Is your web browser also running on the server? The `allow from {MY_IP}` directive looks at where the request is coming from, which is probably not the same as the server, unless you are running both browser and http server on your local machine.

Comment: @MarkkuK. Hmmm... I thought my server would request it. Would there be another solution with blocking the direct access to the pdf files?

Comment: Are you talking about this kind of thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782200/htaccess-to-block-direct-access?rq=1 ?

Comment: @MarkkuK. probably yes, but I'm going to try the answer of AbsoluteZERO first tommorow. Thanks for suggesting this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the referring website to see if it's your own with `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@http?://\1/.*
RewriteRule .*\.pdf [NC,F]
```

That will fail with a forbidden directive (403 error). NC is case insensitivity. The server would need to be configured to show something in the event of a 403 error.

**In PHP**
Additionally you can check this sort of thing with a dynamic page that allows the download. Here's an example of how to do this with PHP:

```
<a href='/download.php?f=myfile&fd=mypath'>Download my PDF</a>
```

We're taking the `.pdf` off of the name in the link for security reasons. You could do something like `base64_encode` the name, but this won't stop a knowledgeable attacker from trying to exploit your system. The `f` variable is the filename (pre-period) and the 'fd' would be the folder (or path).

Example dirs could include `pdfs` or `resources/pdf`.

It can't start or end with a `/`. We're not allowing periods in paths or filenames so someone can't do something like `pdf/../../..`.

Code for `download.php`

```
<?php
if((preg_match('!^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$!',$_GET['f']))&&(preg_match('!^[^/][/A-Za-z0-9_-]+[^/]$!',$_GET['fd']))){
//we're hard-coding the line so someone can't spoof something like .htaccess
$tempPath = $_GET['fd'];
    $tempFilename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$tempPath.'/'.$_GET['f'].'.pdf';

    //Make sure it's a real file
    if(is_file($tempFilename)){
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $serverName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        //check the referrer
        if(strpos($referrer, $serverName)){
            $new_filename = $_GET['f'].'.pdf';
            // We'll be outputting a PDF
            header('Content-type: application/pdf');

            // It will be called downloaded.pdf
            $hString = 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$new_filename.'"';
            header($hString);

            // The PDF source is in original.pdf
            readfile($tempFilename);
        } else {
        //offsite link
        header('Location: /download_policy.php');
        exit(); 
    }
    } else {
        //maybe an old file? Give them the homepage
        header('Location: /');
        exit(); 
    }
} else {
    //hacking attempt
    header('Location: /');
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: The way you said this all is really great! I'll try to use this tommorow, I'll also then reply if it worked or not!

Comment: I tried the .htaccess file and it works perfectly! I've still got one question about it, on the 404 page I'm getting this: 'The requested URL /downloads/PDF/[NC,F] was not found on this server.' What is the [NC,F] supposed to be?

Comment: And how can I specify the location of the PDF file in the <a href='/download.php?f=myfile'>Download my PDF</a> link? If I can do that that would be really perfect to use it.

Comment: Nvm fixed it! I used your script (editted) and it works perfect!